# Filtering a PivotTable by Boolean

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2011

The source data for my Excel PivotTable looks like the following (this is a simplification):

```
id name score
1 john  15
2 james 2
3 pat   14
4 jake  12
...
```

I have a PivotTable that uses this as a data source. Now, what I want to do is have the PivotTable only consider entries if their id is less than 100. This is theoretically achievable by having a Report Filter on id, and de-selecting any number greater than 100. But that's rather absurd.

How can I filter out data using a Boolean constraint? I've tried various methods, none of which worked. It seems like calculated fields are the key, but it doesn't seem possible to create a filter on calculated fields.

I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac, if that makes a difference. I'm a programmer, but I've never programmed in Excel, so if that's the solution, I'd request baby steps. :) Thank you!

Comment: Are you open for an alternate suggestion?

Comment: Yup. What've you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, In Excel 2011, you cannot use a report filter to apply any kind of filter. You have to manually check/uncheck the values that you want or don't want.

The alternative that I can think of is to insert a column before your data and enter the formula

`=If(B2<100,TRUE,FALSE)`

and copy it down using Autofill. (See screenshot below)

[image]

Now create a pivot and put the field "Less Than 100" in the report filter and simply select `TRUE` (See screenshot below)

[image]

If you don't want to go down that path then move the ID field to ROW LABEL from REPORT FILTER where you can use a filter.

Comment: I thought of doing this. It's a shame that Microsoft doesn't seem to care to fully implement this in Excel for Mac. Oh well, thanks for confirming suspicions. Probably the best work-around...

Comment: But then even in Win Excel, you cannot apply filter to `REPORT FILTER`. You have to move them to `ROW LABEL`. :)

Comment: So the features are roughly the same then? Actually, my solution was to put filters on Row Label, and then, by collapsing all rows, I got my desired table. So that's the solution I'm going with for now..

Answer (score 0):

A Report Filter is exactly what I would do, but rather than manually de-selecting the fields as you suggest you would do I would apply a Label filter to be less than the cut-off point, which in your example is 100.

I haven't used Excel on Mac, but on Windows on the PivotTable Field List, to the right of the id field click the little black arrow, and select Label Filters -> Less Than and then enter 100 in the dialogue that pops up.

Given the inherent value of PivotTables is the ability to apply filters exactly for this sort of scenario I don't think I'd do anything more complicated.

Comment: Hey @SiddharthRout , sorry, I'm having trouble downloading that image. Can you try another service? EDIT: Nvm, figured it out. That's where I was looking too. So in that case, the answer is no? Very very sad. Any ideas? Would suck if the solution to this was run over to my Windows VM and blah blah blah...